# Bind - Resolve two domains with a single server

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns, dns-zone

I need a bit of help with BIND (Centos 7.5)
Bit of a back story:

We are running two domains on the network. One called company.domain.com and one called comp.domain.com

company.domain.com has devices with 192.168.100.x IP Addresses

comp.domain.com has devices with 10.1.100.x IP Addresses

My problem is that when I try to resolve a name from company.domain.com with just its short name it works fine, but when I try to do the same with comp.domain.com it fails and I need to enter the full address for it to be resolved.

Is there any way of telling the DNS server that if the requested address cannot be found in company.domain.com to look in comp.domain.com instead of timing out?

(Don't ask me about why we have two domains, I would like to know too. It was done by the previous manager ;D)

Any help is highly appreciated! :)

---

Thanks a lot!

Yes I'm aware it's not great using short names but its near-impossible to tell engineers to do something differently after doing it for the past couple of years!

I'll play around with the windows and linux solutions and see what happens as the DNS server will serve both.

Thank you for the responses! :)

Comment: You simply need to tell your resolvers to try more DNS suffixes when resolving short names. This isn't neither a name server issue nor it's problem.

Answer (score 4):

Using short names is bad practice and should be avoided. It's best practice to always use fully qualified domain names. A whole lot of other stuff will break, either now or in the future, if you continue using short names. If possible, convert all your existing clients to use FQDNs.

That said, this isn't a problem with the DNS server, but with the clients. They need to be configured explicitly to search multiple domain names. For instance, on Linux, you would change the `search` option in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

```
search company.example.com corp.example.com
```

Answer (score 3):

As Michael Hampton points out, this is something that can be addressed on the clients. For Windows clients, it's the DNS Suffix Search List. It can be configured via Group Policy, or through a GUI -- Network and Sharing, select your Local Area Connection, Properties, IPv4 Properties, Advanced, DNS tab, then add company.domain.com and comp.domain.com to the list.

You can also do it programmatically, via registry editing or WMIC. See https://superuser.com/questions/198231/append-dns-suffixes-via-windows-command-prompt for some ideas.